# Acting on Synchronous Promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

I have a few javascript functions that return promises. I'm using `.then` to act on the data returned from those functions. However, is the order guaranteed in the below code? Will `result2` get processed after `result`?

```
const test = promiseReturningFunction(data);
test.then((result) => {
  doStuff(result);
});
const test2 = promiseReturningFunction2(data2);
test2.then((result2) => {
  doStuff(result2);
});
```

Or should this be rewritten along the lines of:

```
const test = promiseReturningFunction(data);
test.then((result) => {
  doStuff(result);
}).then(() => {
  const test2 = promiseReturningFunction2(data2);
  test2.then((result2) => {
    doStuff(result2);
  });
});
```

In short: is `.then` blocking?

Comment: No, it's not blocking. If you want them to execute successively, put the second inside the then of the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the order of `then` callbacks on *independent* promises is not guaranteed. This is pretty much necessary to allow concurrent processing of multiple asynchronous tasks.

If you need a particular order, you need to explicit chain your promise callbacks.

In your case, if you just need the two `doStuff` calls to run after each other, but want to concurrently process the two `promiseReturningFunction`s, you can use

```
const p1 = promiseReturningFunction(data);
const p2 = test.then(doStuff);
const p3 = promiseReturningFunction2(data2);
Promise.all([p2, p3]).then((stuff, result2) => doStuff(result2));
```

If you want to have the two `promiseReturningFunction`s run sequentially, then your second snippet is fine.

Answer (score 2):

No, `.then()` is not blocking. In the first code snippet, you don't know if `result` will be processed first or `result2`.

You could try the [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax, it's easier to understand:

```
(async () => {
  const result = await promiseReturningFunction(data);
  doStuff(result);
  const result2 = await promiseReturningFunction2(data2);
  doStuff(result2);
})();
```

`await` means that the execution of this code will be stopped until the promise returned by `promiseReturningFunction` is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

First one is asynchronous there is no guaranty for result1 after result2

```
promiseReturningFunction(data);
.then((result) => {
  doStuff(result);
})
.then(()=>promiseReturningFunction2(data2))
.then((result2) => {
  doStuff(result2);
})
.catch((err)=> /* Error handling **/);
```

Try this structure please

make sure doStaff is not any I/O operation or else you have make them promise returnable function